# error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gnu, c++, g++

I want to Build GCC 11 from source on Ubuntu 20.04.
I had some problems in making package for ROS and hence I decide to update my GNU.
my gcc and g++ versions are 11.1.0

when I extract the downloaded version of gcc and try to configure it with

```
../gcc-releases-gcc-11.1.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-11.1.0 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-11.1
```

I encounter below error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... yes
checking for libphobos support... yes
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 accepts -g... no
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-gnatbind... no
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-gnatmake... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++11... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++0x... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with +std=c++11... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with -h std=c++11... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with -std=c++0x... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with +std=c++0x... no
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc-11.1.0 supports C++11 features with -h std=c++0x... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
```

I searched a lot but I could not solve. Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to build it from source on an OS that already has it?

Comment: The C++ bits probably need to be routed through `g++` but there's not enough configuration information present to see if it's using `CXX` or how the compilers were selected for.

Comment: @thrig what additional information is necessary?